# Using semaphores in LINUX

Tags: c, linux

I have a task to do and predict the output of a certain code.
The question is what will be the output of X?,is semarg.array affects in someway the output if so,so how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
union semun{
    int val;
    unsigned short *array;
    struct semid_ds *buf; 
    struct seminfo  *__buf; 
}
int main() { 
    int x, semid; 
    union semun semarg;
    semid=semget ( IPC_PRIVATE , 1 , 0600 ); 
    semarg.array=0;
    x=semctl ( semid , 0 , SETALL , semarg ); 
    printf ( "x=%d\n" , x ); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using octal numbers on purpose?

Comment: Yes,This how we should do it.

Comment: Start by defining `union semun` as in the man page for semctl, even if you don't use all the members. They can affect size, padding, etc. Don't use the mystery '0600' flag, but use the IPC_ flag values. Are you sure you want to "fail if key exists" while not "create if key is nonexistent"?

Comment: Since you're not creating a semaphore set (no IPC_CREAT), `semid` is -1. `semctl` will also return -1, setting errno.

Comment: mpez0 is this because semarg.array=0,because as I understand we have to allocate with semarg.array an array,then set values in it and then we can use in SETALL,GETALL,etc.
so in this case the output will be -1?